# How to list the Project properties in openstack

Tags: openstack

we have several projects created in openstack stein release. we have created all the projects with an additional property (like OU and location) like this:

```
openstack project set --property OU=cloud-ops <project name or ID>
```

`openstack project show`: This command shows the property field with the value on it.

`openstack project list --long`: this only shows ID, Name, description, long, Enabled.

How can we list the projects along with their property field value which was set at the time of creation of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a direct API request to Keystone. For example:

```
T=$(openstack token issue -f value -c id)
curl -H "x-auth-token: $T" http://1.2.3.4/identity/v3/projects | 
python -m json.tool | more
```

This will show the property. If you don't like the JSON format, you need to process it, for example with a tool like `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

with this API I can get the info of all the projects but I need to get the name of the projects with only the single field values.